# RestKit loading SQLite Data

Tags: objective-c, restkit

My idea is to load an existing sqlite database filled with data into my object store for RestKit. If I do the following, it works and I got the data.

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://www.myurl.com"];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:DB_FILENAME_SEED_DB usingSeedDatabaseName:DB_FILENAME_SEED_DB managedObjectModel:nil delegate:self];
objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;
```

But what I want to do is to make the loading into the store later on in a method, something like that:

```
- (void)loadSeedDatabase
{
    [FileUtility deleteNormalDatabaseFile]; // do I have to do that?

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore    objectStoreWithStoreFilename:DB_FILENAME usingSeedDatabaseName:DB_FILENAME managedObjectModel:   

    [[objectManager objectStore] managedObjectModel] delegate:self];

    objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;

}
```

I am not sure if I have to delete the already created local sqlite db. If I call this method, locally the DB is correct - my filled sqlite db is there. But if I do some fetch requests, nothing is coming back.

Andy idea what I have to change or what the problem is?